# Store and retrive value from bit(2) column in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot, enums

I need to add values something like
0 - ACTIVE,
1 - INACTIVE,
2 - DISCHARGED

In my database and the column datatype I am using is `bit(2)` I am able to store it in database
using enum

Here is my enum

```
public enum Status {
  ACTIVE,
  INACTIVE,
  DISCHARGED
}
```

I am able to store the value in database using `Status.ACTIVE.ordinal()` but not able to fetch the value from DB.

How can I fetch the value from database in java?

Comment: You have to create a converter https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Comment: Retrieve ordinal value from database and convert to enum using Status.values()[ordinal].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch the value of `bit(2)` column as `integer` from DB we need to use the `CAST()` function

`SELECT CAST(colName AS unsigned int) as aliasName FROM tableName`

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Full answer:

add jpa and mysql-connector dependency to your pom.xml file:

```
<!-- JPA -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- MySQL connector -->
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

After that, you should create interface (for example, SomeDataRepository), that extends CrudRepository.

```
public interface SomeDataRepository extends CrudRepository<Status, Integer> {
}
```

Then you fetching data from database becomes pretty easy (also as other work with db):

```
@Autowired
SomeDataRepository someDataRepository;
public List<Status> getData() {
    return someDataRepository.findAll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what I am looking for. I need to fetch bit values from database and compare it with enum. I am receiving false always